# Dancer2 eclipse integration?

Tags: eclipse, perl, dancer, epic

I want to use dancer2 from eclipse? I have done Dynamic web projects on Java where all the

directory structures are itself generated by eclipse.I searched google couldn't find any documentation.

If I want these

> 1. If I say new project then it should generate the file structure for
>      dancer2.
> 2. I can configure and run the server from the Eclipse itself.

Note: I already have EPIC plugin installed and is working.I am on linux.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can run/debug Dancer2 application in your Eclipse IDE with following steps:  
1.Create a new Perl project with "File->New->Perl project"  
2.Import all the source code with "Import->General->File System" into your new Perl project.

Now you have a Perl Dancer2 project. There's an extra thing you need to do before you run/debug the project directly inside Ecipse:  
Copy or rename the app.psgi to app.pl, then modify ->to_app to ->dance. Now you can right click app.pl and run it as "Local Perl" application.

The psgi file was for running under plack command. That was introduced in Dancer2. It was app.pl in Dancer which needs no modification.